# mutate_if() multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

```
mpg |>
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) |>
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.logical, as.factor) |>
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric)
```

I have the above code. Is there a more simple way to write this code without calling `mutate_if` three times?

Comment: did you try `dplyr::case_when`?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) of `mutate_if`, it's been superseded by `across()`.

So the above code could be written as:

```
library(dplyr)

mpg %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character) | where(is.logical), as.factor),
         across(where(is.integer), as.numeric))
```